# Itunes api for music store list

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs

I am learning angular, for that i was use itunes api for my references. I want to list music albums and click that album i want to show details. I have found one url but in that there is no unique id. I want to unique id from each one from the list of albums. I have include that url below,

[enter link description here](https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=211192863&entity=song)

In this json, I did't get unique id from each item of the list. please provide correct url for get information and detail view of each items. If i get correct url i will practices small application in angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using,

[https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&media=music](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack%20johnson&media=music)

From this i get track id, and passed in to

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=trackId&media=music

i passed this url and get detail page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first result from the URL you linked is:

```
{"wrapperType":"collection", "collectionType":"Album",
{""artistId":211192870, "collectionId":211192863,
{""artistName":"Louis Prima & Gia Maione", "collectionName":"Let's
{"Fly With Mary Poppins", "collectionCensoredName":"Let's Fly With
{"Mary Poppins",
{""artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/gia-
{"maione/id211192870?uo=4",
{""collectionViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/lets-fly-
{"with-mary-poppins/id211192863?uo=4", "artworkUrl60":"http://is2.
{"mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/5e/4c/b0/5e4cb014-26cd-
{"7b64-6dd6-b845750f88ce/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"htt
{"p://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/5e/4c/b0/5e4cb014
{"-26cd-7b64-6dd6-b845750f88ce/source/100x100bb.jpg",
{""collectionPrice":9.99, "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit",
{""trackCount":12, "copyright":"℗ 1965 Buena Vista Records",
{""country":"USA", "currency":"USD",
{""releaseDate":"2007-01-16T08:00:00Z", "primaryGenreName":"Jazz"}
```

Here's the URL to get those album details from the **collection ID** in that result:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=211192863&entity=album
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I am getting same record for all this api. My requirement was, want to get song album list and when i click on that link i want to go to detail view, I have done code in angular, But i didnt get correct api in itunes.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all the data that you need is being returned from the iTunes API JSON and you need to parse it to extract the data you want to use and make your own links for your application.